# cakephp: Use save method , I want to update modified time when data no changed

Tags: cakephp, time, save

Please help me solve this problem , thank you very much.

part 1 : data was changed , i use [ `$this->abcModel->save($abc);`], the `abcTable's` modified column was changed .  `===>` that is OK.

Part2 : data was no changed, i also want `abcTable's` modified column was changed,
How to do deal with ? 
(if show me an example, will be more better to understand.)

> using version: cakephp 3.3

Comment: What version of cake are you using?

Comment: Exactly what is your query? Please share your code too.

Comment: Have solved ,Thank you everyone.   ---> Use this: $this->model->touch($data); Rf.https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp version : cakephp 3.3

`$this->Model->touch($data);`

[Rf.]
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's Assume that you have a form with following fields.

```
Name: XYZ 
Number :077777777
**save** button.
```

It has form action edit/update

**Case 1:** User make changes and save the form.
**Case 2:** User do not make any changes and saves the form.

In either case, you should call your controller edit(or update) function.
your NAME AND NUMBER fields will be available in your controller and can be accessed via 
$this->request->getData() method.
Ideally, you will need two fields for timestamps as below: 
              'CREATED_ON' and 'UPDATED_ON'

you can use touch method as you mention but in an ideal world it will be better to write a behaviour to your model. it will update timestamp every time you create a new record or make changes/save to the record.

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior;

/**
 * Modify built in CakePHP's Timestamp class's default config so no configuration is necessary for use in this project.
 */
final class CustomTimestampBehavior extends TimestampBehavior
{
    /**
     * Default config
     *
     * These are merged with user-provided config when the behavior is used.
     *
     * events - an event-name keyed array of which fields to update, and when, for a given event
     * possible values for when a field will be updated are "always", "new" or "existing", to set
     * the field value always, only when a new record or only when an existing record.
     *
     * refreshTimestamp - if true (the default) the timestamp used will be the current time when
     * the code is executed, to set to an explicit date time value - set refreshTimetamp to false
     * and call setTimestamp() on the behavior class before use.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'implementedFinders' => [],
        'implementedMethods' => [
            'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
            'touch' => 'touch',
        ],
        'events' => [
            'Model.beforeSave' => [
                'CREATED_ON' => 'new',
                'UPDATED_ON' => 'existing',
            ]
        ],
        'refreshTimestamp' => true
    ];
}
```

and call it from your model table. Something like below:

```
   public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);


        $this
            ->addBehavior('CustomTimestamp');
```

This way you don't need to call $this->model->touch($data) manually everytime. The behavior will take care of it whenever it creates or saves.

Ref: https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TimestampBehavior.html